# clerify doubts about wso2 ESB 4.6.0

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I'm a new user to deal with wso2.now I'm using wso2 ESB 4.6.0 management console and wso2 DSS 3.1.0 and for database purpose postgresql .
.At this stage a learnt to create database in postgtesql,connect it to the DSS and then create a proxy service in ESB and execute it to make various operations.

-Please tell me what should i do next and how?

-Is their any other source to refferred than http://docs.wso2.org/?

-How to create mediation sequence for inserting a record into database?

Answer (score 0):

Following [blog](http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-create-mysql-data-service-using.html) explains how to create data service using mysql, instead of mysql you can put postgre driver and jdbc url and add the postgre driver.

This [second post](http://sparkletechthoughts.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-use-wso2-payload-mediator.html) explain how to  create a proxy for the same data service

Comment: thanks.really it is useful for me.now what can i do next?i have to clear my basic concept within 2 months.please guide me

Comment: Well it depends what you want to do.. above two exaples shows how to create a data service and then proxy it using wso2 ESB and insert records to database. Please let me know your requirement so  I can guide you

Comment: how to create a sequence mediator and how can i display required output on client side?